# Simple jQuery blur function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having one of those moments were I can't get a simple piece of code to work. Despite spending just over an hour on this, I can't get this piece of code to work;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title><?php echo 'Test'; ?></title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"><!-- jQuery stylesheet -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script><!-- jQuery libary -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script><!-- jQuery UI -->
</head>
<body>

<script>
$("#target").blur(function () {

    alert("Handler for .blur() called.");

});
</script>

<form>
    <input id="target" type="text" value="Field 1">
    <input type="text" value="Field 2">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

I've run my code through a HTML 5 validator to ensure it wasn't something stupid and I've ensured I'm using the latest version of jQuery. The strange thing is, I can make the code work on jsFiddle.

Comment: because your script is running before the input element is made, either put the script at the bottom or use `$(document).ready`. And it would work in jsFiddle because by default the code you put in the js box is run onload

Comment: script is not getting the target id, put the script at the bottom of the body

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(function(){

    $("#target").blur(function () {

        alert("Handler for .blur() called.");

    });
});
```

You need to update your script to the like written above. That is add a wrapper.

You are binding an event using jquery. However, it is not necessary that when your script executes, jquery has been loaded by then, hence, the binding does not happen, hence, the function does not get triggered.

You need to add a wrapper of on ready of jquery, which make sures that all the binding of events and script execution is done once the dom is ready.

Here, I have created a plunker for you with working version - http://plnkr.co/edit/Xhur8f1ur194ii6XlRby?p=preview

Comment: Thank you. I knew it would be something simple!

Answer (score 2):

Add it in a ready function

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input").blur(function(){
        alert("This input field has lost its focus.");
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

Enter your name: <input type="text">
<p>Write something in the input field, and then click outside the field to lose focus (blur).</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

put the function in document.ready

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#target").blur(function () {

    alert("Handler for .blur() called.");
  });
});
</script>
```

or put script tag of end of the body

Answer (score 1):

Please wrap your js code into

```
$(function(){

// your code 
});
```

it will be

```
  <script>
    $(function(){
      $("#target").blur(function () {
        alert("Handler for .blur() called.");
      });
    });
  </script>
```

Here is the reference https://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 1):

Your JavaScript is running before the `input` elements are rendered, so there's nothing to attach the event to.  Either move your script to the end of the page or wrap it in `$(function(){...})`.  Doing the latter makes the script wait for the `DOMReady` event fired by the browser before executing.

Option 1:

```
<body> 
  <form> 
    <input id="target" type="text" value="Field 1"> 
    <input type="text" value="Field 2"> 
  </form>
  <script> 
    $("#target").blur(function () {
      alert("Handler for .blur() called."); 
    }); 
  </script> 
</body>
```

Option 2:

```
<body>
  <script> 
    $(function(){
      $("#target").blur(function () {
        alert("Handler for .blur() called.");
      }); 
    });
  </script> 
  <form> 
    <input id="target" type="text" value="Field 1"> 
    <input type="text" value="Field 2"> 
  </form>
</body>
```